# Update inner attribute of JSON with jq

Tags: json, unix, command-line-interface, jq

Could somebody help me to deal with jq command line utility to update JSON object's inner value?

I want to alter object `interpreterSettings.2B263G4Z1.properties` by adding several key-values, like `"spark.executor.instances": "16"`.

So far I only managed to fully replace this object, not add new properties with command:

```
cat test.json | jq ".interpreterSettings.\"2B188AQ5T\".properties |= { \"spark.executor.instances\": \"16\" }"
```

This is input JSON:

```
{
  "interpreterSettings": {
    "2B263G4Z1": {
      "id": "2B263G4Z1",
      "name": "sh",
      "group": "sh",
      "properties": {}
    },
    "2B188AQ5T": {
      "id": "2B188AQ5T",
      "name": "spark",
      "group": "spark",
      "properties": {
        "spark.cores.max": "",
        "spark.yarn.jar": "",
        "master": "yarn-client",
        "zeppelin.spark.maxResult": "1000",
        "zeppelin.dep.localrepo": "local-repo",
        "spark.app.name": "Zeppelin",
        "spark.executor.memory": "2560M",
        "zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext": "true",
        "spark.home": "/usr/lib/spark",
        "zeppelin.spark.concurrentSQL": "false",
        "args": "",
        "zeppelin.pyspark.python": "python"
      }
    }
  },
  "interpreterBindings": {
    "2AXUMXYK4": [
      "2B188AQ5T",
      "2AY8SDMRU"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also tried the following but this only prints contents of `interpreterSettings.2B263G4Z1.properties`, not full object.

```
cat test.json | jq ".interpreterSettings.\"2B188AQ5T\".properties + { \"spark.executor.instances\": \"16\" }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works using jq 1.4 or jq 1.5 with a Mac/Linux shell:

```
jq  '.interpreterSettings."2B188AQ5T".properties."spark.executor.instances" = "16" ' test.json
```

If you have trouble adapting the above for Windows, I'd suggest putting the jq program in a file, say my.jq, and invoking it like so:

```
jq -f my.jq test.json
```

Notice that there is no need to use "cat" in this case.

p.s. You were on the right track - try replacing *|=* with *+=*

Comment: Great to know it's so much simpler!

Comment: Using a powershell prompt on Windows should work too if you don't have a terminal emulator.

Comment: @JeffMercado I use unix, 'cat' usage here is absolutely valid syntax in unix systems.

Comment: @snowindy: My comment was directed to the Windows command prompt issues. I personally don't use it whenever I can, only when necessary.